# What is the significance of the central pentagonal element of this war memorial?

Tags: armed-conflict, history, symbols

These photos are of a war memorial in NY State, USA. The central feature is a large 5-pointed star which has a 'cenotaph' element that is also 5-sided:

[image]

Larger photo of the whole thing:

[image]

*In situ*:

[image]

It seems like the points of the pentagon are aligned with the points of the star.

What is the significance of the central element? It reminded me somewhat of a 'cenotaph', is it standing in for a tomb?

Comment: I am wondering how this is related to politics?

Comment: @convert it's a question about a war memorial. War memorials are erected (and taken down) for political purposes.

Comment: If you're asking about the significance of the pillar's cross section being pentagonal, it was probably chosen because the US likes to use 5-pointed stars.

Comment: @phoog I was focused more on the pillar in its entirety though I agree that detail is interesting. I assumed it was indeed because it sort of matches the star.

Answer (score 1):

The **Madison County Veterans Service Agency** and the **Madison County Veterans War Memorial Corporation (WAVEM)** both have Facebook pages (which I didn't go to, because, you know... Facebook!). I also saw a tangential [newspaper article](https://www.oneidadispatch.com/2021/11/12/veterans-honored-by-madison-county-war-veteran-memorial-corporation/) that showed a different (blurry) angle of the central pillar, showing it has plaques attached:

[image]

So cenotaph is a reasonable guess, but your best bet is to go to the Facebook pages where they will likely have historical descriptions and documentation.

For what it's worth, the article mentions that it's a WWI memorial.

Comment: Good idea, thanks. FWIW It may have started with WWI but I'm pretty sure there were at least additions for WWII and Vietnam.